# No puedo incluir carrousel en laravel include

Tags: laravel, blade

Gente como va?

Lo que quiero hacer es a mi home incrustarle dos carrouseles, estos carrouseles se van a repetir en el sitio por lo que me gustaría programarlos en su propio archivo blade.

El problema que tengo es que no se están mostrando a pesar de que ya los incluí en la vista con include('')

**layout/app.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
HTML HTML...
        <main class="py-1">
            @yield('content')
            @yield('uploadProduct')
            @yield('profile')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**content.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">

    <div id="EntreEstasDivApareceElSliderConInclude">
    @include('slider')
    </div>
    <div id="EntreEstasDivApareceElSliderConInclude">
    @include('carrousel_last_products')
    </div>


</div>
@endsection
```

**slider.blade.php**

```
@section('slider')

SLIDER PRUEBA SLIDER PRUEBA

@endsection
```

**carrousel_last_products.blade.php**

```
@section('carrousel_last_products')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>

@endsection
```

No estoy entendiendo bien..

Agradezco de antemano!

Comment: No tenés que poner @section en las plantillas de lo carouseles, solamente el html

Comment: Gracias, era eso!!